# Rails - Sunspot solr is not starting in development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, ruby-on-rails-5, sunspot-rails, sunspot-solr

While I am executing following command, after bundle solr related gems

> bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:start

I got permission error:

```
Creating directory /apps/test_app/current/solr
rake aborted!
Errno::EACCES: Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir - /apps
/home/rp/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@test_app/gems/sunspot_solr-2.2.6/lib/sunspot/solr/installer.rb:48:in `block in execute'
/home/rp/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@test_app/gems/sunspot_solr-2.2.6/lib/sunspot/solr/installer.rb:37:in `each'
/home/rp/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@test_app/gems/sunspot_solr-2.2.6/lib/sunspot/solr/installer.rb:37:in `execute'
/home/rp/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@test_app/gems/sunspot_solr-2.2.6/lib/sunspot/solr/installer.rb:17:in `execute'
/home/rp/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@test_app/gems/sunspot_solr-2.2.6/lib/sunspot/solr/server.rb:174:in `install_solr_home'
/home/rp/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@test_app/gems/sunspot_solr-2.2.6/lib/sunspot/solr/server.rb:40:in `bootstrap'
/home/rp/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@test_app/gems/sunspot_solr-2.2.6/lib/sunspot/solr/server.rb:55:in `start'
/home/rp/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@test_app/gems/sunspot_solr-2.2.6/lib/sunspot/solr/tasks.rb:10:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/rp/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@test_app/gems/rake-11.3.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/home/rp/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@test_app/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/home/rp/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@test_app/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => sunspot:solr:start
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

It would be great help if anyone had idea regarding this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't know, must be some permission issue! :p

Comment: Please check the permission of this directory `apps/test_app/current/solr`

Comment: I don't have any directory named as `apps` in my home directory

Comment: Try this `sudo chmod 777 -R /home/your_complete_path/test_app` i,e for me `sudo chmod 777 -R  /home/ab/projects/any_app`

Comment: Giving same error! huh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sunspot configuration should be this `config/sunspot.yml`

```
development:
  solr:
    hostname: localhost
    port: 8982
    log_level: INFO

test:
  solr:
    hostname: localhost
    port: 8981
    log_level: WARNING
```

Ref: [github repo](https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot#configuration)